# Sitecore 7:Calling one xml control from other xml control

Tags: xml, controls, sitecore, sitecore7

I need to call(on click of a button or link)a custom  xml control from another xml control in sitecore.

Is this possible?If so,please provide me some direction on this.

Thanks,
Suhas

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "call" a custom XML control?

Comment: Basically I want to add a link/button from "http://localhost/sitecore/shell/Applications/Dialogs/Internal%20link.aspx" control which will launch another xml control say http://localhost/sitecore/shell/default.aspx?xmlcontrol=ImageSelector where user can select an image and on click of ok source of image is copied to a custom textbox in  first  xml control(http://localhost/sitecore/shell/Applications/Dialogs/Internal%20link.aspx).

Comment: For best documentation and example the sitecore source code is the best place to see.. Use any .net decompiler app such as dotpeek, justdecompile, and reflector to understand how sitecore does it and follow yourself or check existing .xml sheer ui files, hopefully then you will find the answer.. As one below.. (This comment was to help you learn how to learn) Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is copy-pasted from the decompiled code of the Edit button click method in the device editor (presentation details) dialog box, which opens an additional modal:

```csharp
SheerResponse.ShowModalDialog(urlString.ToString(), "720", "480", string.Empty, true);
```